# Polygon intersection fails after an st_wrapx operation

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query that conditionally uses `st_wrapx` followed by an intersect. I've observed that the intersect fails unexpectedly even when 'wrapped' polygon is identical to the 'non wrapped' version

The following snippet illustrates the issue;

```
with
input(geom) as (
    select st_polyfromtext('POLYGON((-71. 42.,-72. 43.,-71. 43.,-71. 42.))')
),
wrap(geom,wrapped_geom) as (
    select geom,
           st_wrapx(st_shiftlongitude(geom), 180, -360)
    from input
)
select
       st_asewkt(geom),
       st_asewkt(wrapped_geom),
       st_asewkt(geom) = st_asewkt(wrapped_geom) wkt_are_equal,
       st_asewkb(geom) = st_asewkb(wrapped_geom) wkb_are_equal,
       st_intersects(geom,wrapped_geom) intersects,
       st_intersects(st_asewkt(geom)::geometry,st_asewkt(wrapped_geom)::geometry) recast_intersects
from wrap;
```

With the following results:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+---------------------------------------
st_asewkt         | POLYGON((-71 42,-72 43,-71 43,-71 42))
st_asewkt         | POLYGON((-71 42,-72 43,-71 43,-71 42))
wkt_are_equal     | t
wkb_are_equal     | t
intersects        | f
recast_intersects | t
```

note that:

- the WKB abd WKT for the two geometries are identical
- the insect operation returns `false`
- by round-tripping to WKT the intersect now is `true`

This is the version I have:

```
POSTGIS="2.5.5" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.3-CAPI-1.11.3 b50468f" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.4.4, released 2020/01/08" LIBXML="2.9.11" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" RASTER
```

Comment: works fine under 3.2.1

Comment: yes, i re-tested under pg12/pg 3.0.4 and didn't see the problem - maybe something that got fixed after